# Exact meaning of ∃x

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am a little bit confused about the meaning of quantifier ∃x

Some definitions make it sound like *There is exactly one x* and some make it sound like *There is at least one x*

I have this expression:

∃x (P(x)∧ Q(x))

Does it mean *find exactly one x for P(x) and Q(x)* or does it mean *find one or more x for P(x) and Q(x)*?

Comment: It means that at least one such $x$ exists that makes $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ true.

Comment: "at least one"...

Comment: The latex notation is $\exists \, ! \, x$ instead of just $\exists \, x$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde. You should say that the exclamation mark is used to denote "*exactly one*", i.e. $\exists!$ denotes "there is exactly one".

Comment: @DietrichBurde. But the meaning of $\exists x$ is *not* "there is exactly one", but "there is at least one".

Comment: However, too prove "$\exists x : P(x)$" it is enough to find *one* $x$ such that $P(x)$. Too prove $\exists! x : P(x)$" one should find one $x$ such that $P(x)$ and then show that if also $P(y)$ then $x=y$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde. The question was about the meaning of $\exists x$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde. That doesn't change much. Yes, you only need to find one $x$ to prove $\exists x$. But that doesn't mean that $\exists !$ should be used instead, since to prove the $\exists !$ you also need to prove uniqueness.

Comment: No, I just mean that for a unique $x$ (he was asking "Does it mean _find exactly one x for P(x) and Q(x)_") you need to use $\exists \, ! \, x$, and not $\exists \, x$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde. What you meant wasn't obvious. And what does "find exactly one" mean? Does it mean that you just need to find one but there might exist more, or does it mean that you need to find one and should prove that there are no more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Exactly one* is often denoted as

$$\exists!$$

Comment: (+1) And it is often said as 'There exists a unique...'

Comment: @Eff: or "one and only one".